# Where did my apache module get installed

Tags: apache, centos, atlassian-crowd

I'm trying to get Crowd Apache Connector working. I've installed the modules. If I do a `yum info` it tells me that it's installed. If I do `httpd -M` it's listed as a shared module. However, it's not in `apache/modules/`

When I try the `LoadModule` in the pre main include, I get the error that it cannot load it into the server because it doesn't exist.

The error after trying to load the module:

```
Configuration problem detected on line 1 of file /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf.tmp:  : Cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_authnz_crowd.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_authnz_crowd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory --- /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf.tmp --- 1 ===> LoadModule authnz_crowd_module modules/mod_authnz_crowd.so <=== 2LoadModule authz_svn_crowd_module modules/mod_authz_svn_crowd.so --- /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf.tmp ---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. After reinstalling it, I checked the httpd.conf file and found that it was installing it to:

`/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authnz_crowd.so`

Knowing that I was able to get it working.